# Is Wine stable enough for production?

Tags: linux, emulation, wine

I have a open relationship with Linux, i use it on and off and i just got into the latest ubuntu and got a change to try out wine and it seemed to take any windows app and make it like i was actually using windows.

I wanted to know is wine that stable to use in production/businesses or are there problems that i haven't come across yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wine v1 is [considered stable](http://www.winehq.org/announce/1.0).  "Stable" is always a bit relative and I think that because of the nature of Wine and its complexity as well as the always-changing applications running on it themselves it would always be somewhat touchy.

That said, I think that if you go by the different classes of [application compatibility in the Wine App DB](http://appdb.winehq.org/) and only use Gold ones then one can probably safely say it is reasonably stable.  The Wine community is great and I'm sure will be a great help.

For multiple workstation, mission-critical use I think you would be better off going with a commercial spin-off of Wine like [CodeWeavers CrossOver Linux](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/cxlinux/) and have the benefit of commercial support.